# Wait for external script to load before the React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS app and the page structure loosely looks like this:

```
<Head>
<Navigation>
<Page>
<Footer>
```

I have a DTM script that I need to load in the `<Head>` component and then there are tags that I am firing in the `<Page>` component. But the problem is, the tags in `<Page>` starts firing before the DTM script get's loaded onto the page.

So, is there a way to let the DTM script in the `<Head>` tag load first before the `<Page>` component loads? I was looking to use "componentwillmount" but it's being deprecated.

Can someone please advice how can I tackle this issue?

Comment: does the external script provide a callback?

Comment: You could use [`next/head`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head) to place the `<script>` of the DTM script in the `<head>` - that'll hopefully load before nextjs' code. Ideally you'd want to place it in `<body>` before wherever nextjs places its code.

Comment: I've already used react-load-script with nextjs, it has an onLoad callback you can use. Also you can use nextjs lazy load on the components you want to be rendered after the component mount.

Comment: I am using next/head already in my <Head> component. I have added the scripts there. I am actually making a call to one my /static/js files and that js file then loads the external DTM script based on the current hostname. But, the DTM functions in <Page> components are firing before the script is completely loaded and executed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I put the tinyMCE script in next/head and it's about a 50% chance the script will be loaded by the time the page is mounted. And if it isn't, my editor doesn't display.

Answer (score 6):

You could listen to the script load event from your `<Page>` component using vanilla javascript.
in your [custom _document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document):

```
<script id="dtm" src="dtm.js" />
```

then in the `<Page>` component:

```
document.getElementById("dtm").addEventListener('load', () => {
  // DTM is loaded
})
```

Answer (score 2):

next.js offers `onLoad`, which triggers once the external script is loaded:

```
<Script src="https://example.org/script.js"
    onLoad={() => {
        console.log('script has loaded')
    }
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Head` in any components by Nextjs.
How about you add `Head` in `Page` and put `<script/>` inside